# Multiple buffers of the same file

Tags: buffers, filesystem, quickfix

I ran into a problem when using the quickfix feature of vim. When I open up my source file in vim, a buffer of that file is created, and its name is shown on the status bar, let's say `main.cpp`.

Then I compile it with `:make` and jump to next error with quickfix. Because the error message my compiler outputs is always absolute path, e.g. `c:\folder1\folder2\main.cpp`. If I jump to that error location, then a new buffer of the same file will be opened, but with the absolute path filename.

Then when I edit either of them and save it, the other buffer won't get updated and that's really annoying. I tried `set autoread` but it doesn't help at all. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I am running vim on windows.

Comment: That shouldn't really happen - are you using symlinks (so two paths point to the same file)?

Comment: I don't think so. I am using windows and I didn't do anything like symlinks.

Comment: Windows is case insensitive - maybe you have different casing somewhere in the path?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem, thanks for leading me to that direction! Quickfix's output is always lowercased, so in order to match with its output, I changed the entire path to lowercase, except the leading ":C", since I can't change it. Because they have different casings, jump-to-error still directs me to a new buffer. Do you know what I can do to have the quickfix window output path with correct casing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `fileignorecase` is set (`set fileignorecase?`) even though it should be the default on Windows:

```
                'fileignorecase' 'fic' 'nofileignorecase' 'nofic'
'fileignorecase' 'fic'  boolean (default on for systems where case in file
                                 names is normally ignored)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        When set case is ignored when using file names and directories.
        See 'wildignorecase' for only ignoring case when doing completion.
```

You are using the native Windows vim exe (not cygwin)?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. After I set it it fixed the problem. Thanks a lot man!